# Ajax call binding multiple HTML controls with a single request

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I am trying to bind multiple HTML select controls using Ajax calls, but my process is getting failed after all my efforts. What is wrong here?

This is the web service which returns five data tables:

```
[WebMethod]
public List<List<ListItem>> DealerLoad(string otype, string target, string para)
{
    ds = AL.ExecuteDataSet("sp_dlr_NewDealer_query", CommandType.StoredProcedure, new[]
    {
        new MySqlParameter("OType", otype),
        new MySqlParameter("Target", target),
        new MySqlParameter("id", 0)
    });
    List<ListItem> list1 = new List<ListItem>();
    List<ListItem> list2 = new List<ListItem>();
    List<ListItem> list3 = new List<ListItem>();
    List<ListItem> list4 = new List<ListItem>();
    List<ListItem> list5 = new List<ListItem>();

    List<ListItem> list = new List<ListItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++) {
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[i].Rows)
        {

            list.Add(new ListItem
            {
                Value = dr[0].ToString(),
                Text = dr[1].ToString()
            });

            if (i == 0)
            {
                list1 = list;
            }
            else if (i == 1)
            {
                list2 = list;
            }
            else if (i == 2)
            {
                list3 = list;
            }
            else if (i == 3)
            {
                list4 = list;
            }
            else if (i == 4)
            {
                list5 = list;
            }
        }
    }
    return new List<List<ListItem>>{list1, list2, list3, list4, list5};
}
```

This is the jQuery Ajax call:

```
var url = '../WebDeal.asmx/DealerLoad2';
var data = {};
var control = $('#ddl_country').attr('id') + ',' +
                  $('#ddl_countryallow').attr('id') + ',' +
                  $('#ddl_center').attr('id') + ',' +
                  $('#ddl_Superior').attr('id') + ',' +
                  $('#ddl_SuperExe').attr('id');
data.otype = 'select';
data.target = 'GetLoadData';
data.para = '';
BindControl(url, JSON.stringify(data), control);
```

**The Binding Control Method**

function BindControl(xurl, xdata, xcontrol) {

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: xdata,
    url: xurl,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        onSuccess1(result, xcontrol);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(error.responseText);
    }
});
```

};

#### And the successful call

```
function onSuccess1(responese, control) {

    var chk = control;
    var controlarr = String(chk).split(',');
    if (controlarr.length == 1) {
        control.empty().append('<option value=0 selected="selected">Select</option>');
        if (responese.d != null) {
            $.each(responese.d, function () {
                control.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
            });
        }
        hideload();
    }
    else {
        $.each(controlarr, function (index, values) {
            var controls = $('#' + values);

            controls.append('<option value=0 selected="selected">Select</option>');
            $.each(responese.d[index], function () {
                controls.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
                hideload();
            });
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: WHat does the log say?

Comment: it says nothing ....only Success method throws error on this point **(responese.each(index)**

Comment: what does the console say?

Comment: what error?where?

Comment: **$.each(responese.each(index), function () {** has error of invalid method each(index)  ..... I also had tried    **$.each(responese.d[index], function () {**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[WebMethod]
public List<List<ListItem>> DealerLoad(string otype, string target, string para)
{
    ds = AL.ExecuteDataSet("sp_dlr_NewDealer_query", CommandType.StoredProcedure, new[]
    {
        new MySqlParameter("OType", otype),
        new MySqlParameter("Target", target),
        new MySqlParameter("id", 0)
    });
    List<ListItem> list1 = new List<ListItem>();
    List<ListItem> list2 = new List<ListItem>();
    List<ListItem> list3 = new List<ListItem>();
    List<ListItem> list4 = new List<ListItem>();
    List<ListItem> list5 = new List<ListItem>();

    List<ListItem> list = new List<ListItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++) {
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[i].Rows)
        {

            list.Add(new ListItem
            {
                Value = dr[0].ToString(),
                Text = dr[1].ToString()
            });

            if (i == 0)
            {
                list1 = list;
            }
            else if (i == 1)
            {
                list2 = list;
            }
            else if (i == 2)
            {
                list3 = list;
            }
            else if (i == 3)
            {
                list4 = list;
            }
            else if (i == 4)
            {
                list5 = list;
            }
        }
    }



    // *Please try to bind the dropdown here rather than clientside*

    return new List<List<ListItem>>{list1, list2, list3, list4, list5};
}
```